# Google Maps Balloon lost style

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, dictionary

I'm wondering what did I do wrong.
I'm using bMap ( http://www.blocsoft.com/bmap/ ) to get the Google maps, and in the demos, everything looks correct.
My version doesn't look so good. I've lost all the rounded corners. My guess is that this is a common mistake, but I have no idea, because the map-baloon styles are supposed to be inline. Besides that - I have tried disabling my CSS completley, and the corners are still square. Not only that but the box looks messed up a bit.

Any ideas where should I start to debug this ?

The HTML from Inspector:

```
<div style="z-index: 106; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"><div style="display: none;"><div style="width: 107px; height: 137px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 21px; top: 26px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -784px; top: -102px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 1029px; height: 255px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/cb/mod_cb_scout/cb_scout_sprite_api_003.png"><div style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 5px; width: 94px; height: 75px; background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211); z-index: 1;"></div><div style="width: 95px; bottom: 38px; z-index: 1; left: 7px; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 9px; color: gray; background-color: white; position: absolute;">Loading...</div><img style="position: absolute; left: 7px; top: 5px; width: 94px; height: 75px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; opacity: 0.25;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/transparent.png"></div><div style="width: 21px; height: 26px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 63px; top: 127px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -441px; top: -102px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 1029px; height: 255px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/cb/mod_cb_scout/cb_scout_sprite_api_003.png"></div></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 257px; top: 84px; cursor: default; z-index: 307;"><div style="width: 48px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 162px; top: 123px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -49px; top: -715px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 44px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 157px; top: 130px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -44px; top: -722px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 40px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 152px; top: 137px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -39px; top: -729px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 36px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 147px; top: 144px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -34px; top: -736px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 31px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 142px; top: 151px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -29px; top: -743px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 27px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 137px; top: 158px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -24px; top: -750px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 23px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 132px; top: 165px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -19px; top: -757px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 18px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 127px; top: 172px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -14px; top: -764px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 14px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 122px; top: 179px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -9px; top: -771px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 10px; height: 8px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 117px; top: 186px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -4px; top: -778px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="width: 97px; height: 25px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; z-index: 1; -moz-user-select: none; left: 113px; top: 99px;"><img style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: -691px; width: 690px; height: 786px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/iw3.png"></div><div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 321px; height: 122px; overflow: hidden; -moz-user-select: none; background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(171, 171, 171);"></div><div style="width: 321px; height: 122px;"><div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; opacity: 0.7; right: 12px; top: 12px; z-index: 10000; cursor: pointer;"><img style="position: absolute; left: -18px; top: -44px; width: 68px; height: 67px; -moz-user-select: none; border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png"></div><div style="cursor: default; position: absolute; left: 18px; top: 18px; z-index: 2; overflow: auto; width: 287px; height: 88px;"><div style="overflow: auto;"><h2>Frederikshåb Hundeskov</h2><a href="/?p=424"> More Information</a></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the Chrome or Firefox "inspector" tools to see what CSS rules apply to the element (and what rules don't)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are using V3 of Google Maps and comparing the results to V2 demos in the bMap site. The balloons (InfoWindows) have rounded corners in V2, and square corners in V3. I didn't see CSS mentioned in the bMap site.

There is a utility library for balloons with rounded corners, called [**InfoBubble**](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/) [(example here)](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html) but I'm not sure how easy it is to incorporate with bMap.

About the box looking messed up, is it [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11042656/1325290)? There's a CSS fix to apply to your map div:

```
#map_canvas label { width: auto; display:inline; }
#map_canvas img { max-width: none; max-height: none; }
```

Comment: #map_canvas img { max-width: none; max-height: none; } fixed the wierd cross of the balloon